# How to fix GitHub Copilot failure? Suddenly connecting to login doesn't work

Tags: github

Just now when I opened IDEA with the intention of knocking out code, I realized that GitHub Copilot was disabled, and when I logged back into copilot, it reported the following error.

Sign in failed. Reason: Request signInInitiate failed with message: connect ETIMEDOUT 20.205.243.168:443, request id: 7, error code: -32603

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the copilot plugin, but that didn't do the trick. And I checked "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically" in IDEA's server certificates settings, but it still didn't work. My copilot is student certified and has a 2 year expiration date.

Comment: Probably a transient problem on their side. I've had that happen. Try again later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's great that it's not my problem, I'll wait for him to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your hosts file; add

```
140.82.113.5 api.github.com
```

Might have to try a few more times.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 with JetBrains IntelliJ 2022.1.

Context: this error also occurs on first time setup in some corporate enterprises, because the plugin is not yet configured with a personal access token.

Fix:
Create a hosts.json file in the following location: C:\Users\<active user name>\AppData\Local\github-copilot

The format should be:
{"github.com":{"user":"<GitHub user id (not email)","oauth_token":"<personal access OAuth token classic version, not fine-grained>"}}

Create a new throwaway GitHub personal access token (OAuth classic token) in the Developer Settings section of the GitHub settings and update the hosts.json file. Don't set it to expire. Note: once everything is working, the token in this file may change. Leave this file alone once it's all working.

Save the file and restart IntelliJ. Then try logging in to GitHub through the GitHub Copilot's plugin UI and enjoy the plugin.